# Remove Keys in json array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this

```
[{"cname":"NCPB"},{"cname":"NBK"}]
```

Which I'm getting from [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

on mysql result

How can I achive this  `["NCPB","NBK"]`    From JSON OBJECT ABOVE.

Comment: You mean `["NCPB","NBK"]`, right?

Comment: yes @Don'tPanic

Comment: Show us your mysql fetch code. That's how you need to fix this, _before you json_encode_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I can answer this without seeing your exact code. Basically, you're currently fetching your query results with something like this and using `json_encode` on the result of that:

```
while ($row = $query->some_fetch_method()) {
    $results[] = $row;               // you're building an array of associative arrays
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Instead, just fill the results array with that specific column instead of the entire row.

```
while ($row = $query->some_fetch_method()) {
    $results[] = $row['cname'];      // you need to build an array of strings instead
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

You should get the array of query results into the format you want *before* you use `json_encode`. Otherwise, you'll have to decode the JSON string you just made, reformat the result of that, and reencode it:

```
 $json = json_encode(array_column(json_decode($json), 'cname'));
```

or use some weird regex or something. It doesn't seem to make sense to undo what you've already done, though.

If you don't get what I mean, edit your question to add the code that fetches your query results, and I'll show you an example based on your exact code, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: I appreciate that You got my question right .... But `echo json_encode($results);` can't print anyhting

Comment: @NicholasSnr Just to be sure, you didn't use the exact code from my answer, right? `some_fetch_method()` doesn't really exist, it's just an example to show the general idea of how to change your existing code. This is something that _does work_, in general. As far as why it isn't specifically working for you, I'd need to see more of your code to understand.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT cname FROM sub_targets";

     $query = mysql_query( $sql );
     
 while ($row = $query->mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $results[] = $row;               // you're building an array of associative arrays
}
echo json_encode($results); `

Comment: Using `$results[] = $row['cname'];` instead with that should give you the result you want. The only reasons that would display nothing would be (1) Your query failed to execute for some reason (2) Your query executed successfully, but returned no results (3) There's an error somewhere else in your script that ended execution before the result could be displayed.

Comment: Thanks...but how do assign `$results[] ` array to variable say `$MYARRAY`?

Comment: You can name it whatever you want. It doesn't have to be called `$results`.

Comment: I have done `$MYARRAY  = $results[]; ` then `echo json_encode($MYARRAY  );` I get an error

Comment: Don't include the `[]`. It's just `$MYARRAY = $results;` The `[]` part is for adding an item to the array.